# Associate relationship afterwards

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

Version used: Laravel 5.4

We have a post and that post can have several pictures associated with it. We use a controller to store the post and an other one to store the pictures.

We set the relationship in the models like so:

```
class Post extends Model
{
    public function pictures()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Picture::class);
    }
}

class Picture extends Model
{
    public function post()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Post::class);
    }
}
```

When I go to the form to create a new post, I can add pictures to that post **before** I actually store the post. Which means that when I store a picture I still don't have a post id to associated it to.

My questions is:

- Using **only** php, is there a *clean* way to associate the pictures to the post before or afterwards ?

The solution I am currently using is that when I go to the form to create a new post, a blank new post is created before hand and I pass the id on the url. It has to be a better way to do it.

Comment: What is your problem to create a post first and then picture ?

Comment: The pictures is a part of the create post form. So when the user add its pictures the actual post is not yet created. The association should be done when the post is stored.

Comment: Then also. from the same form you can create post first and then upload picture in the same controller function. if you are worrying about  that in some rare case post has created and pictures didn't upload then you can use laravel's query builder transaction or you can collect the post id and delete in case of failure. you can use try catch block.

Comment: The number of pictures uploaded is unknown. Can be none, 1 or 100. That's why I use a separate controller. The form to add a picture has only one input file on it.

Comment: Are you using different form for uploading the picture ? and different form for creating the post ? but picture can be uploaded before creating the post ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Once you are on the form to create the post, you can access another one to upload your pictures. Picture is uploaded before creating the post.

Comment: You can check my answer. if it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

First create the form when user access the create post page (as you are already doing).

Suppose this is your function which is showing the create post view

```
public function showCreatePost()
{
   $post = Post::create(['field_name' => '', // put your attributes]);

 // pass other data as well if you want.
   return view('your_create_view',compact('postId',$postId));
}
```

change your route of imageupload which will have postid . for example

```
Route::post('post/image/{postId}','SomeController@somefunction');
```

create one route for editing the post and use it for editing the post which will have post id.

```
Route::post('post/edit/{postId}','SomeController@someOtherfunction');
```

Now use these two routes as form action and you can edit the post and upload the image. route example below

Showing the id in url is not a good idea. so by this way you can try and let me know if you face any problem.

Comment: It looks a lot like what I am doing now. A bit cleaner because you pass the id in the form action only.

Comment: Ya, but it would not be visible to user. so whenever user will save the details then you will hit the edit route.